# Пайп в реулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как сделать регулярное выражение для текста "| UA" в конце строки? Без кавычек. Делаю так: "\| BY$" Но оно срабатывает независимо от наличия | - пайпа. как сделать чтобы пайп учитывался? Регулярное выражение используется в feedbro.

Comment: Извините ошибся "\| UA$"

Comment: Вообще регулярка правильная. Можно тут проверить: https://regex101.com/r/NPJ2Ya/1/ если она у вас не работает возможно вы задаете ее в каких то особых условиях, например ваш язык в двойных кавычках интерполирует некоторые вещи в строках, например ему надо передавать `\\|` что бы в итоге получилось `\|`

Comment: Спасибо. Опытным путем выяснил, что в feedbro правильно писать так: \|\ UA$ То есть экранировать и пайп и пробел.

Answer (score 1):

Опытным путем выяснил, что в feedbro правильно писать так: \|\ UA$ То есть экранировать и пайп и пробел.